# Load a mocked class in Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito

Is there an easy way, using Mockito, to load a mock class when another is requested OR to override the test ClassLoader?

Basically I have a class Foo that has a member "ClassA" in it. I want to replace to use "TestClassA" instead of "ClassA" during testing. I don't want to use dependency injection because it doesn't make any sense for actual operation. (It can never be anything other than ClassA)

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It can never be anything other than ClassA

...except that it is, in your test. Test code is real code, and though that doesn't mean it should sneak into your production application, it does mean that you need to *write in the flexibility you need for all of its use cases*, and *that includes testing*.

Mockito works via subclasses: A `mockFoo` created by `mock(Foo.class)` or `@Mock Foo mockFoo` is actually a proxy subclass Mockito created that overrides each of Foo's methods. As you can tell from that description, Mockito thus cannot change the behavior of *every* Foo object and especially cannot change the type of the object returned from `new Foo()`.

You have two options, that I can see:

1. Accept a ClassA or InterfaceA instance in *one of your constructors*. If you put your tests in the same Java package as your class under test (even in a different source tree), you can even make the constructor package-private, or keep it private and create a static factory method like `createForTest(ClassA)`.

   Example:

   ```
   public class ConsumerToTest {
     private final ClassA classA;

     /** For public use. */
     public ConsumerToTest() {
       this(new ClassA());
     }

     /** For use in tests. */
     ConsumerToTest(ClassA class) {
       this.classA = classA;
     }

     // ...
   }
   ```
2. Use [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock), which has a Mockito integration known as PowerMockito. Though Mockito uses pure proxy subclasses and code generation, PowerMockito actually rewrites the bytecode of the system-under-test. This means that you can mock static methods and constructors that Mockito couldn't adjust on its own through polymorphism.

Personally, I very much prefer solution 1: The code is yours to control, and as long as you're clear that your test is a first-class consumer of your system-under-test, you're free to design it to be testable in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it by constructor is what I prefer.

For example

```
public class Foo {
     private ClassA classA;

     public Foo(ClassA classA) {
         this.classA = classA;
     }
 }

public class FooTest {
     private Foo foo;

      @before
      public void setup() {
          foo = new Foo(Mockito.mock(ClassA.class);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple to do this using `Mockito`.

```
public class Foo {
     private ClassA classA;
}
```

Test will look like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FooTest {
  @Mock
  private ClassA classA;

  @InjectMocks
  private Foo foo = new Foo();

  //Test methods
}
```

That's it, you have mocked ClassA!